# Reason for text/plain pattern "*,v" in shared-mime-info?

Tags: mime-types, freedesktop, rcs

The freedesktop.org media type database `shared-mime-info` has [a filename pattern `*,v`](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/shared-mime-info/-/blob/b969e1c74e7c905a96c1590f5350a264dbaa83ae/data/freedesktop.org.xml.in#L5854) associated with MIME type `text/plain`, and I can't figure out why - if only because `,v` and `*,v` are basically useless as search terms!

[The 2008 commit that added the pattern](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/shared-mime-info/-/commit/bf4994fb0b4d15f227be0f71f6f22322fc53897f) doesn’t explain it, though the test case does point to [a bug on RedHat’s Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=430203). There, someone had “RCS files” with filenames ending in `,v`, and the bug was that they were being recognised as audio files. Without further context, I can only guess that “RCS files” refers to Revision Control System, rather than radar cross-section data or Autodesk ReCap scan files…

Why did this one user’s weird experience lead to a change in `shared-mime-info` for everyone? Was it a widespread problem, perhaps because RCS was known to generate files with that ending? Why was adding it to `shared-mime-info` an appropriate response† to the bug, rather than (say) finding out why these random files were being treated as audio?

---

† I say “response”, not “fix”, because it’s not clear to me that it *did* fix the user’s problem. The bug was closed because it ceased to occur in later versions of the software, which isn’t explicitly credited to the change in `shared-mime-info`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RCS indeed creates files with the `,v` suffix:

```
$ mkdir RCS
$ echo hello > hello.txt
$ ci hello.txt 
RCS/hello.txt,v  <--  hello.txt
enter description, terminated with single '.' or end of file:
NOTE: This is NOT the log message!
>> test file
>> 
initial revision: 1.1
done
$ ls RCS
hello.txt,v
```

and they don't look exactly like the original file, so it may indeed be prudent to recognize them as something different.

```
$ cat RCS/hello.txt,v 
head    1.1;
access;
symbols;
locks; strict;
comment @# @;


1.1
date    2021.08.28.14.44.57;    author ilkkachu; state Exp;
branches;
next    ;


desc
@test file
@


1.1
log
@Initial revision
@
text
@hello
@
```

It also seems to be able to process at least some binary data, though does that in a line-based manner.

Why they would be recognized as audio files in particular, that I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

There's enough information in the question for you to answer it yourself.  The '*,v' is present to prevent audio-files which were checked into RCS from being interpreted as audio-files (because the file-formats differ, and would produce an error if one attempted to **play** them).

An RCS file can contain *binary* data, because it treats that as just another "string".  The [manual page](https://www.manpagez.com/man/5/rcsfile/) mentions this without providing much detail:

> Strings are enclosed by **`@`**.  If a string contains a **`@`**, it must  be  doubled; otherwise, strings can contain arbitrary binary data.

There are several audio/video formats which can be distinguished by a program (such as [`file`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=file&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD%2013.0-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html)) which inspects the contents of the file.  However, MIME is oriented to identifying files by their name (in particular their ["suffix"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types)), and some systems will attempt to automatically infer the MIME type using only the filename.  That's inherently error-prone, and the `'*,v'` is a workaround to accommodate the implementation.

Comment: Two points. One, the bug reporter said the files in question were *not* audio files. The example file (and I think from context *all* of the files) had the extension `.ftn,v`, and `.ftn` is apparently an extension for Fortran source files. And two, I’m not asking “what’s the benefit of this?”, and I’ll edit the question to try and clarify that.

Comment: OP said this *"the bug was that they were being recognised as audio files."* which does not agree with your comment.

Comment: I *am* the OP. ;-) The bug is that they were *recognised* as audio files, even though they *weren’t* audio files. From the bug report: “…a bunch of RCS
files… other various kinds of data file (there's no single audio file on the disk)” (by which I think they mean “**not a** single audio file”).

Comment: sure: but the question did not add that "even though" clause, and RCS files can contain binary content such as audio files.  (fwiw, I do this with png files).

Comment: Ah, I’m sorry it wasn’t clearer. I guess I thought the “even though” was implied: if “doing X” is a bug, then it implies that the software is doing X *even though* it shouldn’t.